# Is there a mysql feature to allow parallel replication per query?

Tags: mysql, replication

When adding columns or indexes to big tables in a master salve setup, replication lag occurs.

My understanding is that replication occurs in a single thread on the slave, and statements get executed in FIFO or queue structure, and this is done to preserve the integrity of data.

So if unique constraint is added on master, and then new data is added with duplicate values, the slave should first add the unique constraint before adding the data to avoid issues.

However there are many use cases where this kind of integrity is not required. For example if I add a secondary index to a table, there is no need for this type of single thread, I would like it to continue inserting other data and replicating even if the index replication is not done yet, avoiding replication lag.

So to my question, is there a command such as:

```
SET sql_log_bin_blocking=0;
ALTER TABLE user ADD INDEX `index1` (`age`);
SET sql_log_bin_blocking=1;
```

This query would get replicated to all slaves, but it would not be blocking and not cause replication lag.

Is there something like that currently?

Comment: Which version of MySQL/MariaDB?  There have been significant improvements in this area (`ALTER` and Replication) in recent versions.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention. MySQL 5.7 using InnoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that will truly allow no replication lag is an OSC tool like [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) or [gh-ost](https://github.com/github/gh-ost).

- You can read and write to the table while the ALTER is running either on the source or replica instances.
- They run the ALTER concurrently on the source and replica instances. That is, the ALTER starts on the replica soon after it starts on the source; it doesn't have to wait for it to finish on the source before it starts on the replica, which is how DDL is replicated normally.

There is no way to make an alter table run in parallel in current versions of MySQL. Version 8.0 introduced the beginnings of parallel query execution, but so far it is only used for a very limited case: clustered index reads, which improves performance CHECK TABLE and SELECT COUNT(*) with no where clause. See https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/23/mysql-8-0-14-a-road-to-parallel-query-execution-is-wide-open/. It will take many more years before this is implemented for all operations.

You could run the ALTER TABLE on the source without writing the change to the binary log, and then run the same ALTER TABLE directly on the replica. But there is necessary table locking during any DDL statement, and this will block writes to the table anyway, so it is likely to result in replication lag (unless you are never writing to that table anyway).

The parallel replication feature in MySQL does not allow a given change to be run in parallel, and it does not eliminate the table-locking required by DDL statements.

Comment: Isn't the table-locking only on some ALTER TABLE operations? For example based on this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-operations adding a column does not lock the table in most cases. It seems there are some edge cases such as adding an auto-increment column that does lock the table.

Comment: @BernardWiesner, during online DDL, any writes to that table are queued up. If the queue becomes longer than 128MB, further writes are blocked. In any case, when the online DDL is done, any queued changes are applied to the table immediately, and while that is executing, the table is locked. Online DDL isn't quite what you think it is.

Comment: oh wow, I didnt know that... thanks for letting me know. Do you have some link where I can read more about that in detail? thanks

Comment: Here's the documentation page that describes it, the page following the one you linked to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-online-ddl-space-requirements.html

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake: if the buffer for queued changes fills up, it doesn't block further changes. It _cancels_ your online DDL statement that was in progress, and then applies the queued changes to the unaltered table.

Comment: I just want to confirm, on the docs it says "If a temporary log file exceeds the upper size limit, the ALTER TABLE operation fails and all uncommitted concurrent DML operations are rolled back." Does this mean the queued changes will be applied or rolled back?

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I did an experiment, I created a large table with 1 million rows of random data. I did an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN that would run for several minutes. Then in a second window I did an UPDATE to change existing data. The window running the ALTER TABLE got _ERROR 1799 (HY000): Creating index 'PRIMARY' required more than 'innodb_online_alter_log_max_size' bytes of modification log. Please try again._ but the UPDATE continued to run to completion.

Comment: I see, thanks for testing that. Maybe the docs are a little off, or dont explain that so clearly.

Comment: Hi, I also tried reproducing on local with around 1 million rows, and could reproduce same behavior as you. However I could not reproduce the part you mentioned earlier about "table locking". I could not experience any table locking, even as the queue was being applied. If there was some table locking it was very small I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

- Newer versions of MySQL have a way to have multiple slave execution threads.  But, beware, an `ALTER` being executed by one thread will block other treads from doing some actions with that table.  The latest version allows some flavors of `ADD COLUMN` and `ADD/DROP INDEX` are virtually non-blocking.  And they run faster, so they are clogging the replication stream (FIFO) for less time.
- Newer versions of MySQL have better `ALTERs` -- they allow
- See `pt-online-schema-change` as a relatively efficient way to do certain `ALTERs`.  It may help you.
- Consider running the `ALTER` separately on each server; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_sql_log_bin

  ```
    # on Primary server:
    SET sql_log_bin = OFF;
    ALTER ...;
    SET sql_log_bin = ON;

    # On Replica, one at a time, perhaps with each offline:
    ALTER ...;     # (assuming there are not Replicas hanging off this Replica)
  ```
- Vertical partitioning can avoid needing to `ADD COLUMN`.  (Less invasive, but not 'clean'.)

FIFO...  Before about 5.6, yes, the replication stream was single-threaded.  After that, replication became more sophisticated.  First it would allow some parallel execution when two queries did not touch  the same *database*.  The latest versions allow some forms of parallelism as long as it still keeps the Replica identical to the Primary.  That is, 'preserve the integrity of data'.  References:

- https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/02/10/estimating-potential-for-mysql-5-7-parallel-replication/
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-implementation-details.html (and other pages)

Comment: hi, is there some reference link regarding this part: "The latest versions allow virtually form of parallelism that still keeps the Replica identical to the Primary. That is, 'preserve the integrity of data'."

Comment: @BernardWiesner - I updated my Answer with 5.7 specific links.